# Kendo numeric textbox range validator message

Tags: kendo-ui

Kendo numberic textbox is not showing my Range validator message. It Always showing 
"Please enter a value less than or equal to 100." But i want to change it to my defined message.
How can i change range validator message? How can i show my defined message "Length should be 1-100"?

Code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter length")]
[Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Length should be 1-100")]
public double? Length { get; set; }
```

Required errormessage ("Enter length") is showing properly 
but range errormessage("Length should be 1-100") is not showing.
It Always showing 
"Please enter a value less than or equal to 100."

Answer (score 3):

Data Annotations:

```
[Display(Name = "Project Cost")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Range(typeof(decimal), "1", "10000", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1:C} and {2:C}")]
public decimal? ProjectCost { get; set; }
```

Razor Markup:

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.Equipment.ProjectCost).Min(null).Max(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<input  validationMessage="Please enter {0}" />
```

Hm, don´t know if I understand you correctly but for me this works:

```
<input pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" class="k-textbox input-mini k-invalid" required="" data-required-msg="This is a required filed!" validationmessage="Please enter only Numbers!" aria-invalid="true">
```

If the user clicks submit without any inputs the required message appers. 
If the user fill in something else than numbers than the validation message appears.

Comment: Yes i tried, but still same fixed error message, If i enter value more than 100 then it should show my defined message, But still its showing same message, "Please enter a value less than or equal to 100. "

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor( model => model.Length ).Deferred() )
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="Length" id="Length" data-val-required="Enter length" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range="Length should be 1-100" data-val-number="The field Length must be a number." data-val="true" class="input-validation-error">
```

And it shows your desired message if you enter a number greater than 100.